# Population matrix for disease modelling in R

Tags: r, matrix, modeling

I am new to R and need some help getting started. I have an empty matrix (col:5-50 years and 10000 rows). I need to populate it in such a way that infected individuals are a 1 and uninfected are 0. This needs to be random across the different age groups, and such that every column has at least one 1 and the disease prevalence is 10%. Every year the population ages and the 50-year olds leave and a new set of 5 year olds enter (so population number goes up and down), and the new entries also get infected randomly.

Do I use a Leslie matrix code for this, where do I even start?
Thank you.

....................

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Is this a project you've been assigned by someone?  Can you get help locally getting started? What do the rows represent? Individuals? i.e., is the population size fixed at 10,000?

Comment: For simplicity, perhaps it'd be easier to start with (say) 5-8 years and 10 rows, so you (and we) can visualize the problem more easily. Once you figure out how to do it for a small number of years and rows, you can naturally extend it to thousands as needed. Doing it this way also allows you to perhaps use tools you may be more familiar with to contrive example data (e.g., Excel, Calc, or something else).

Answer (score 0):

A naive implementation?

```r
prevalence <- 0.1
row_count <- 1e4
df <- replicate(46, rbinom(row_count, 1, prevalence)) |> 
  as.data.frame()
colnames(df) <- sprintf('age_%s', 5:50)
df
```